# Memory corruption cause by free()

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm trying to understand how does dynamic memory allocation in C work. So I coded this:

```
typedef struct person{
    int id;
    int credit;
}person_t;

typedef struct list{
    int id;
    person_t * people;
}list_t;

int main(){
list_t * list;
list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
list->people = malloc(10 * sizeof(person_t)); //list for 10 people

free(list->people);
free(list);
}
```

, which appears to be correct. However, when I decided to create functions for allocation\deallocation, double free or corruption error started to appear:

```
void init_list(list_t * listptr, int size){
    listptr = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    listptr->people = malloc(size * sizeof(person_t));
}

void clear_list(list_t * listptr){
    free(listptr->people);
    free(listptr);
}

int main(){
list_t list;
init_list(&list, 10); //list for 10 people
clear_list(&list);
}
```

Output:

```
Error in ./list: double free or corruption (out) : 0x00007ffc1b3fba70
```

Why could that be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're passing `listptr` to `init_list` by value; it's a local variable in that function, and changes to it are not seen outside (i.e. in `main`). So the memory you allocate is practically lost, and then you attempt to `free` memory that hasn't been `malloc`'d, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void init_list(list_t * listptr, int size){
    listptr = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    listptr->people = malloc(size * sizeof(person_t));
}
```

is not correct. You are modifying `listptr` in the function. That does not change anything of `list` in `main`. You need to remove the line fhat changes `listptr` in that function. Use:

```
// listptr is already a valid pointer.
// There is no need to allocate memory for it.
void init_list(list_t * listptr, int size){
    listptr->people = malloc(size * sizeof(person_t));
}
```

You have a worse mistake in `clear_list`.

```
void clear_list(list_t * listptr){
    free(listptr->people);
    free(listptr);
}
```

You are calling `free` on a pointer that was not allocated by a call to `malloc`. `listptr` is a pointer to the object that was created in stack in `main`. Remove the second call to `free`. Use:

```
// listptr is a pointer to an object on the stack in main.
// Trying to call free on it is an error.
void clear_list(list_t * listptr){
    free(listptr->people);
}
```